# Generate Multiple Divs within php code

Tags: php, html, tags, escaping, heredoc

Currently I am trying to loop through a directory grabbing all 14 file names and generate some html using the file names. I have run into some issue of creating HTML elements within PHP, and right now I'm just trying to generate an HTML `div` with an image in it and a line of text underneath 14 times.

I have tried putting empty `php` tags before and after the HTML elements, which didn't work because PHP does not allow `php` elements within another `php` element.

```
<?php   
$dir = "classes/1961/*";
     foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
          {
             <?php 
             ?>
                  <div class="cell-1-9">
                       <img src="images/image.jpg">
                       <p>Dylan Miller</p>
                  </div>
             <?php
             ?>   
          }
?>
```

I need another way of generating HTML elements within PHP.

Comment: What is the output when you remove the starting tags inside the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to close the `<?php` tag in order to revert back to html:

```
<?php   
$dir = "classes/1961/*";
     foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
          {
             ?>
                  <div class="cell-1-9">
                       <img src="<?php echo $file ?>">
                       <p>Dylan Miller</p>
                  </div>
              <?php
          }
?>
```

Comment: you forgot to open php after </div>

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php   
$dir = "classes/1961/*";
 foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
      { 
        ?>
              <div class="cell-1-9">
                   <img src="images/image.jpg">
                   <p>Dylan Miller</p>
              </div>
         <?php   
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the example in my MVC project, [PHP-One](https://github.com/DominicArchual/Php-One), you can do something like this using what's known as HEREDOC syntax:

```
<?php
foreach($Model as $movie)
{
    echo <<<HTML
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <strong>{$movie->Title}</strong> ({$movie->Rating}) - {$movie->ReleaseDate}
        </li>
HTML;
}
?>
```

Adapted for your code, try something like:

```
<?php   
$dir = "classes/1961/*";
 foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
      {
         echo <<<HTML
              <div class="cell-1-9">
                   <img src="{$file}">
                   <p>{$file}</p>
              </div>
HTML;
      }
?>
```

Ref. https://github.com/DominicArchual/Php-One#define-your-view

Footnote: Learning MVC will make you a better developer; also more valuable.

Comment: Your *2nd* heredoc will fail. There shouldn't be anything before and/or after the identifier. It will throw a parse error. See the warning under http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Thanks, Fred.  To elaborate on Fred's comment; the closing delmiter `HTML;` must not have any characters (even blank space) before or after it

Answer (score 1):

Try the HEREDOC syntax.
I'm pasting the user1477388's corrected code: the closing HTML; must NOT be indented.

```
<?php   
$dir = "classes/1961/*";
 foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
      {
         echo <<<HTML
              <div class="cell-1-9">
                   <img src="{$file}">
                   <p>{$file}</p>
              </div>
HTML;
      }
?>
```